# Embedding Javascript into an HTML parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for the proper method to embed javascript into an html parameter. This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
  <img src="source.png" height="<script> if(screen.width == 1920)
                                {document.write('60px');}</script>" 
                                 title="icon"/>
```

I know embedding PHP in this manner can work, but I can not seem to get it to work with Javascript. My limited knowledge on the matter is to blame, and I need some help resolving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any tricks or workarounds that would allow an application like this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the `id="sourceImg"` I added to the element, which **must** be unique per element per page. Not doing this will mean Javascript will not know which element to select, and will pick one.

```
<img id="sourceImg" src="source.png" title="icon">

<script>
if (screen.width == 1920) {
    document.getElementById('sourceImg').style.height = '60px';
}
</script>
```

That either needs to run after the markup falls in the source of the page, or in a `window.onload` event handler. If it runs before the `img` element is available, it will error out.

**NOTE** - JohnFx's method that he describes in the comments below is:

```
<img id="sourceImg" src="source.png" title="icon" onload="sizeMe()">

<script>
function sizeMe() {
  if (screen.width == 1920) {
    document.getElementById('sourceImg').style.height = '60px';
  }
}
</script>
```

This uses the `img` element's `onload` handler. Note that inline event handlers like `onload=""`, `onclick=""`, etc., are typically considered hard to maintain. The above should work, however, as a demonstration, and other routes involve understanding page loading, DOM element availability and other details which are potentially more difficult to understand than a simple example.

**EDIT**

And, *technically*, you could do this:

```
<img id="sourceImg"
     onload="if(screen.width < 1920) this.style.width='60px';"
     src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ae/001_Jornal_Monsenhor_A_Comarca_23_de_Marco_de_1947.jpg/762px-001_Jornal_Monsenhor_A_Comarca_23_de_Marco_de_1947.jpg"
     title="icon">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdN3y/

*Note, I changed the `if` statement to make the change more obvious.*

But **please don't**. It's a bad idea and a bad habit to get into. Spend some time figuring out page loading and DOM availability, it's time well spent.

Comment: This is indeed the correct method, you cannot embed Javascript inside HTML tags.

Comment: You might want to add this to a that executes only after the DOM element has loaded.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a proper method.

Comment: @JohnFx - I understand your point, but a function by itself won't fix it unless it runs after the element is available (either after the `img` falls in the source code, or in an event which calls the code afterwards).

Comment: See my edit Jared. I realized my initial comment came off as implying that a simple function would fix it, but I meant to say that a function that is called from body.onload or something like that.

Comment: @JohnFx - I think something got cut out of the edit; it doesn't actually make sense anymore. `:)`

Comment: @JohnFx - The only question I have, since I have never used the `onload` inline handler on an image, is if there is potential for the image to flash the original. A more appropriate method would be to add an event handler to the page/DOM load, or after the `img` markup on the page.

Comment: Probably the best solution would be to write code in the onload of the body element that does a document.write or create a new img element in the DOM some other way rather than try to inline it on an existing IMG tag.

Comment: @JohnFx - Yeah, no `document.write`. A `document.createElement` is modern, may not be a bad idea (although finding where to put it could be tricky with just DOM methods, something jQuery makes really simple). If you trust CSS media queries, this could be solved without any Javascript and be completely unobtrusive.

Comment: @JohnFx - Using the `onload` handler on an image that progressively loads will cause the image to display in original size until the `onload` handler detects the image has completely downloaded: http://jsfiddle.net/pdN3y/1/ ([Another to test](http://jsfiddle.net/pdN3y/2/).) However, once the element is cached, this doesn't happen.

Comment: @JohnFx - The image could be hidden and then shown, however: http://jsfiddle.net/pdN3y/3/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it that way. You are correct - your PHP is interfering. There are lots of ways to do this, just changing your approach:

```
<script>
    document.write("<img src='source.png' title='icon' " + screen.width == 1920 ? "height='60px'" : "" + " />");
</script>
```

Comment: Oh I don't know that `document.write`ing the element out is really a modern practice, with so many more appropriate methods available...

Comment: I absolutely agree. Like I said, I was just correcting his approach so that it worked. The transition from one language to another is a very personal experience, and sometimes it can b helpful to see an idiom you know translated into the new language, even if it is not an "acceptable" idiom in the new language.